# Type Safety for React Lifecycle Methods

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using TypeScript for a React project. Based on what I can see in the [type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L378) `componentWillReceiveProps`' first argument should be of the same generic type passed to the Component class. I thought that `Component` would already implement `ComponentLifecycle`, but I have also tried using `implements ComponentLifecycle` directly, and I'm still not getting the type safety I would expect.

```
interface Props {
  user: { login: string };
}

class Comp extends React.Component<Props> {
  componentWillReceiveProps({ user }) {
    // I think this should be two errors:
    // `Property `ogin` does not exist on type 
    // Type `string` is not assignable to type 'void';
    return user.ogin;
  }
}
```

However I do not get either error and it seems like the `Props` that get passed into `componentWillReceiveProps` only maintain their types at one level. In order to get this to work, I can write it like so:

```
componentWillReceiveProps({ user }: Props): void {
```

Is there any way to get TypeScript to properly type the generic argument for an implemented interface? Is this a bug in the type definitions?

Comment: Something I've found (but you might have read it already) https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/13897

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a bug. Definition of [React.Component](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/v15/index.d.ts#L302-L327) in typings is:

```
class Component<P, S> {
    constructor(props?: P, context?: any);
    setState<K extends keyof S>(
        state: ((prevState: Readonly<S>, props: P) => (Pick<S, K> | S)) | (Pick<S, K> | S),
        callback?: () => any
    ): void;

    forceUpdate(callBack?: () => any): void;
    render(): JSX.Element | null | false;
    props: Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode }> & Readonly<P>;
    state: Readonly<S>;
    context: any;
    refs: {
        [key: string]: ReactInstance
    };
}
```

There is nothing about lifecycle methods and their types. From the point of view of typescript you are simply extending `React.Component` with new methods and it tries to infer the type of argument from user code in function. When you add types explicitly Typescript understands your intentions and helps you. I now only one way to type this precisely - define Component class as abstract and mark all lifecycle methods as `abstract`. But in this case you will have to override these methods in child class definition, but it is not you want to do most part of time with React. If you just define lifecycle methods on regular class definition like `React.Component` you still can override this definition with other parameters, so typescript wont force you to keep the same shape of function and prevent you from using unknown params. I think it only be fixed by adding `sealed` function attribute to typescript which will prohibit overriding of function type for children.

Comment: But see https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/v15/index.d.ts#L301 -- not only that, but if I add `implements React.ComponentLifecycle<Props, never>` I don't get any errors either.